# Cant edit structure of top navigation menu

Tags: navigation

I have been searching for this for a couple of days and found a lot of places are telling me to edit the navigation file however when i look in this file i cant see where it is structuring my navigation menu.

When i inspect my navigation on my webpage the structure is

```
<ul> -> beginning of the list 
<li> 
<ol> -> first column of nav
<li> ->items in column 
<ol>-> Second column of Nav 
<li> ->items in column
<ol>->3rd column of Nav
<li>->items in coloumn
```

But i want it to be

```
<ul> -> beginning of the list 
<li> 
<ol> -> first column of nav
<li> -> All items in 1 column
```

I have put my navigation.php below because i cant find where it references the structure as i cant see any ol tags.

```
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    /**
     * Category instance
     *
     * @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Category
     */
    protected $_categoryInstance;

    /**
     * Current category key
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_currentCategoryKey;

    /**
     * Array of level position counters
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_itemLevelPositions = array();

    /**
     * Current child categories collection
     *
     * @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Collection
     */
    protected $_currentChildCategories;

    /**
     * Set cache data
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->addData(array('cache_lifetime' => false));
        $this->addCacheTag(array(
            Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::CACHE_TAG,
            Mage_Core_Model_Store_Group::CACHE_TAG
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Get Key pieces for caching block content
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCacheKeyInfo()
    {
        $shortCacheId = array(
            'CATALOG_NAVIGATION',
            Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(),
            Mage::getDesign()->getPackageName(),
            Mage::getDesign()->getTheme('template'),
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(),
            'template' => $this->getTemplate(),
            'name' => $this->getNameInLayout(),
            $this->getCurrenCategoryKey()
        );
        $cacheId = $shortCacheId;

        $shortCacheId = array_values($shortCacheId);
        $shortCacheId = implode('|', $shortCacheId);
        $shortCacheId = md5($shortCacheId);

        $cacheId['category_path'] = $this->getCurrenCategoryKey();
        $cacheId['short_cache_id'] = $shortCacheId;

        return $cacheId;
    }

    /**
     * Get current category key
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCurrenCategoryKey()
    {
        if (!$this->_currentCategoryKey) {
            $category = Mage::registry('current_category');
            if ($category) {
                $this->_currentCategoryKey = $category->getPath();
            } else {
                $this->_currentCategoryKey = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
            }
        }

        return $this->_currentCategoryKey;
    }

    /**
     * Get categories of current store
     *
     * @return Varien_Data_Tree_Node_Collection
     */
    public function getStoreCategories()
    {
        $helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
        return $helper->getStoreCategories();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve child categories of current category
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Collection
     */
public function getCurrentChildCategories()
   {
        $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
        $category   = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
        /* @var $category Mage_Catalog_Model_Category */
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
        /* @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Collection */
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('is_anchor')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('image') 
            ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
            ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
            ->setOrder('position', 'ASC')
            ->joinUrlRewrite()
            ->load();

        $productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
        $layer->prepareProductCollection($productCollection);
        $productCollection->addCountToCategories($collection);
        return $collection;
    } 

    /**
     * Check whether specified category is active
     *
     * @param Varien_Object $category
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isCategoryActive($category)
    {
        return $this->getCurrentCategory()
            ? in_array($category->getId(), $this->getCurrentCategory()->getPathIds()) : false;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve category instance
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Category
     */
    protected function _getCategoryInstance()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_categoryInstance)) {
            $this->_categoryInstance = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
        }
        return $this->_categoryInstance;
    }

    /**
     * Get url for category data
     *
     * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCategoryUrl($category)
    {
        if ($category instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Category) {
            $url = $category->getUrl();
        } else {
            $url = $this->_getCategoryInstance()
                ->setData($category->getData())
                ->getUrl();
        }

        return $url;
    }

    /**
     * Return item position representation in menu tree
     *
     * @param int $level
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getItemPosition($level)
    {
        if ($level == 0) {
            $zeroLevelPosition = isset($this->_itemLevelPositions[$level]) ? $this->_itemLevelPositions[$level] + 1 : 1;
            $this->_itemLevelPositions = array();
            $this->_itemLevelPositions[$level] = $zeroLevelPosition;
        } elseif (isset($this->_itemLevelPositions[$level])) {
            $this->_itemLevelPositions[$level]++;
        } else {
            $this->_itemLevelPositions[$level] = 1;
        }

        $position = array();
        for($i = 0; $i <= $level; $i++) {
            if (isset($this->_itemLevelPositions[$i])) {
                $position[] = $this->_itemLevelPositions[$i];
            }
        }
        return implode('-', $position);
    }

    /**
     * Render category to html
     *
     * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category
     * @param int Nesting level number
     * @param boolean Whether ot not this item is last, affects list item class
     * @param boolean Whether ot not this item is first, affects list item class
     * @param boolean Whether ot not this item is outermost, affects list item class
     * @param string Extra class of outermost list items
     * @param string If specified wraps children list in div with this class
     * @param boolean Whether ot not to add on* attributes to list item
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _renderCategoryMenuItemHtml($category, $level = 0, $isLast = false, $isFirst = false,
        $isOutermost = false, $outermostItemClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '', $noEventAttributes = false)
    {
        if (!$category->getIsActive()) {
            return '';
        }
        $html = array();

        // get all children
        // If Flat Data enabled then use it but only on frontend
        $flatHelper = Mage::helper('catalog/category_flat');
        if ($flatHelper->isAvailable() && $flatHelper->isBuilt(true) && !Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()) {
            $children = (array)$category->getChildrenNodes();
            $childrenCount = count($children);
        } else {
            $children = $category->getChildren();
            $childrenCount = $children->count();
        }
        $hasChildren = ($children && $childrenCount);

        // select active children
        $activeChildren = array();
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            if ($child->getIsActive()) {
                $activeChildren[] = $child;
            }
        }
        $activeChildrenCount = count($activeChildren);
        $hasActiveChildren = ($activeChildrenCount > 0);

        // prepare list item html classes
        $classes = array();
        $classes[] = 'level' . $level;
        $classes[] = 'nav-' . $this->_getItemPosition($level);
        if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)) {
            $classes[] = 'active';
        }
        $linkClass = '';
        if ($isOutermost && $outermostItemClass) {
            $classes[] = $outermostItemClass;
            $linkClass = ' class="'.$outermostItemClass.'"';
        }
        if ($isFirst) {
            $classes[] = 'first';
        }
        if ($isLast) {
            $classes[] = 'last';
        }
        if ($hasActiveChildren) {
            $classes[] = 'parent';
        }

        // prepare list item attributes
        $attributes = array();
        if (count($classes) > 0) {
            $attributes['class'] = implode(' ', $classes);
        }
        if ($hasActiveChildren && !$noEventAttributes) {
             $attributes['onmouseover'] = 'toggleMenu(this,1)';
             $attributes['onmouseout'] = 'toggleMenu(this,0)';
        }

        // assemble list item with attributes
        $htmlLi = '<li';
        foreach ($attributes as $attrName => $attrValue) {
            $htmlLi .= ' ' . $attrName . '="' . str_replace('"', '\"', $attrValue) . '"';
        }
        $htmlLi .= '>';
        $html[] = $htmlLi;

        $html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>';
        $html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
        $html[] = '</a>';

        // render children
        $htmlChildren = '';
        $j = 0;
        foreach ($activeChildren as $child) {
            $htmlChildren .= $this->_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml(
                $child,
                ($level + 1),
                ($j == $activeChildrenCount - 1),
                ($j == 0),
                false,
                $outermostItemClass,
                $childrenWrapClass,
                $noEventAttributes
            );
            $j++;
        }
        if (!empty($htmlChildren)) {
            if ($childrenWrapClass) {
                $html[] = '<div class="' . $childrenWrapClass . '">';
            }
            $html[] = '<ul class="level' . $level . '">';
            $html[] = $htmlChildren;
            $html[] = '</ul>';
            if ($childrenWrapClass) {
                $html[] = '</div>';
            }
        }

        $html[] = '</li>';

        $html = implode("\n", $html);
        return $html;
    }

    /**
     * Render category to html
     *
     * @deprecated deprecated after 1.4
     * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category
     * @param int Nesting level number
     * @param boolean Whether ot not this item is last, affects list item class
     * @return string
     */
    public function drawItem($category, $level = 0, $last = false)
    {
        return $this->_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml($category, $level, $last);
    }

    /**
     * Enter description here...
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Category
     */
    public function getCurrentCategory()
    {
        if (Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')) {
            return Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Enter description here...
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCurrentCategoryPath()
    {
        if ($this->getCurrentCategory()) {
            return explode(',', $this->getCurrentCategory()->getPathInStore());
        }
        return array();
    }

    /**
     * Enter description here...
     *
     * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category
     * @return string
     */

    public function drawOpenCategoryItem($category) {
        $html = '';
        if (!$category->getIsActive()) {
            return $html;
        }

        $html .= '<li';

        if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)) {
            $html .= ' class="active"';
        }

        $html .= '>' . "\n";
        $html .= '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'">'
            . '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span></a>' . "\n";

        if (in_array($category->getId(), $this->getCurrentCategoryPath())) {
            $children = $category->getChildren();
            $hasChildren = $children && $children->count();

            if ($hasChildren) {
                $htmlChildren = '';
                foreach ($children as $child) {
                    $htmlChildren .= $this->drawOpenCategoryItem($child);
                }

            }
        }
        $html .= '</li>'."\n";

        return $html;
    }

    /**
     * Render categories menu in HTML
     *
     * @param int Level number for list item class to start from
     * @param string Extra class of outermost list items
     * @param string If specified wraps children list in div with this class
     * @return string
     */
    public function renderCategoriesMenuHtml($level = 0, $outermostItemClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '')
    {
        $activeCategories = array();
        foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $child) {
            if ($child->getIsActive()) {
                $activeCategories[] = $child;
            }
        }
        $activeCategoriesCount = count($activeCategories);
        $hasActiveCategoriesCount = ($activeCategoriesCount > 0);

        if (!$hasActiveCategoriesCount) {
            return '';
        }

        $html = '';
        $j = 0;
        foreach ($activeCategories as $category) {
            $html .= $this->_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml(
                $category,
                $level,
                ($j == $activeCategoriesCount - 1),
                ($j == 0),
                true,
                $outermostItemClass,
                $childrenWrapClass,
                true
            );
            $j++;
        }

        return $html;
    }
}
```

So i just need to know 1. if i am looking in the correct place for the structure of the navigation and 2. how to edit it?  if you need any more info please just let me know.

My Main aim is to have the All Categories menu in a straight line on the home page and have it as it is on the rest of the website. If i am going about this the wrong way please let me know.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Tried enabling template path hints from admin panel?

Comment: i did that it pointed me to top.phtml where i found the code 

<?php $_menu = $this->renderCategoriesMenuHtml(0, 'level-top', 'sub-wrapper' ) ?>

then it just echoed 'menu' so i found the renderCategoriesMenuHtml function in the Navigation.php

Comment: From re-looking at the element on my webpage i think i may need to find the div "sub-wrapper" as that is the div my structure is in. But i have no idea where to even start looking for that

Comment: what magento version are you working on, and do you want to show this categories in sidebar?

Comment: 1.9.0.1. No not really we want the all categories top navigation to be dropped down on just the front page so it is already visible when the page loads up. However if it is better practice to have the categories in a side bar and just use CSS to make it look like it is dropping down from the top and disable the mouse over on the home page (so the all cats cant drop down) i could talk to my manager about it. We are both new to magento so dont know what the best way of doing this would be. if this has confused you, let me know and will get screen shots for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with version CE 1.7 the top menu is not generated by `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation` anymore.
Instead `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu` is used.
This one dispatches events that basically let you add anything in the main menu.
By default the categories are added via an observer.
And each menu item is rendered by the method `_getHtml` from the same class.
I think that's what you are looking for.